# What is the .NET equivalent of StringBuffer in Java?

Tags: c#, java, .net, string

What is the .NET equivalent of [`java.lang.StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)?

Comment: If Jon Skeet could understand it, I think it's a real question...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx). Note that in modern Java you'd use [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) too. (It's like `StringBuffer`, but without the synchronization - I can't remember the last time I *wanted* the synchronization of `StringBuffer`. Note that the .NET `StringBuilder` isn't thread-safe either, but again, I can't remember the last time I found that to be a problem.)

Comment: You don't want the synchronization of StringBuffer, ever -- it doesn't actually make code thread-safe. See http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008_08_01_archive.html